# How to force normal crash behavior when using setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics-firebase

In an app I'm developing, I'm using Google Analytics to track uncaught exceptions like so:

```
// ...after setting up Google Analytics...
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new AnalyticsExceptionHandler(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()));
```

And this is the handler, the **AnalyticsExceptionHandler** class:

```
public class AnalyticsExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    // Private
    private UncaughtExceptionHandler _defaultHandlerRef;

    public AnalyticsExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandlerRef)
    {
        this._defaultHandlerRef = defaultHandlerRef;
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
    {
        // ...track and send the exception to Google Analytics...
        _defaultHandlerRef.uncaughtException(t, e);
    }
}
```

Thing is, the app never actually crashes, it just freezes. If I remove the **setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()** line then the app crashes normally.

Am I doing something wrong in the above code by passing it to the previous default handler?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070393/replacing-default-uncaught-exception-handler-to-avoid-crash-dialog it might help you

Answer (score 2):

Why not re-throw the exception?

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
{
    // ...track and send the exception to Google Analytics...
    _defaultHandlerRef.uncaughtException(t, e);

    throw e;
}
```